# You can deploy on Windows 10 with MDT?

Tags: mdt, windows-10

Will we be able to deploy Windows 10 with MDT? 
Could we use the same task sequences ( with windows 10 instead 8 )?
Do we need  an update of the toolkit?

Comment: Google `"windows 10" MDT`

Comment: I have deployed a Windows 10 using SCCM with integrated MDT. I assume this would work also for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answers:

Yes, you will we be able to deploy Windows 10 with MDT.

In a very general sense, you COULD use an existing task sequence, swapping Windows 8 for Windows 10 at the "Install Operating System" step. But you will need to test it and see how it goes. I usually recommend creating a new task sequence instead of modifying an existing one.

You DO need to update the Microsoft Deployment Toolkit in order to deploy Windows 10:

- If you are on MDT version 2013, you can follow an unsupported process to get Windows 10 deployment working: http://blog.westmonroepartners.com/make-the-microsoft-deployment-toolkit-mdt-2013-able-to-deploy-windows-10-windows-server-vnext-and-hyper-v-server-vnext-technical-preview/
- Microsoft is working on a new version of MDT (version 2013 Update 1) that will be fully supported for Windows 10 deployment. However, to transition to it, you will need to install the updated ADK for Windows 10 and make additional changes to your environment.

I would recommend applying the unsupported workaround in the blog post above. Once Microsoft releases the final version of MDT 2013 Update 1, you can then transition your MDT environment to it.

Comment: MDT 2013 Update 1 is in preview and supports Windows 10 deployment. No need for an unofficial workaround:
http://blogs.technet.com/b/msdeployment/archive/2015/03/02/microsoft-deployment-toolkit-2013-update-1-preview-now-available.aspx
For builds newer than Build 10041, due to the change in kernel number some additional tweaks are required, but again, not unofficial:
http://blogs.technet.com/b/msdeployment/archive/2015/03/28/mdt-updates-for-windows-10-technical-preview-build-10041.aspx

Comment: There are some additional bugs in the preview version of MDT 2013 Update 1. If your MDT environment is supporting image deployment in a large enterprise, I would be more inclined to deploy the workaround until it is released. But of course, each environment is different and there are pros and cons to both approaches.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. It is distributed in a WIM file so it is deployable via MDT.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, there are updates to the toolkit to deploy windows 10. Whether or not you can use the same TS depends on what you are doing in that TS. The quickest way to find out is to try your existing steps in a w10 deployment